# How to detect bitmap orientation in delphi?

Tags: delphi, bitmap

I need to convert TBitmap to GDI+ Bitmap.

I can't understand a way of determining if TBitmap top-down or bottom-up.

Is it possible to discover the scanline ordering?

Comment: +1 I've used ScanLine a lot and never knew that it might be from bottom to top.

Comment: Why not use the `Bitmap` constructor that takes an `HBITMAP` as input? You can pass it the `TBitmap.Handle`, then you don't need to deal with the raw pixel data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows API to know a bitmap line direction (bottom-up or top-down).
You should call GetObject function to get DIBSECTION struct with BITMAPINFOHEADER data.
But in my practice most of bitmaps has bottom-up pixel line direction.